# Error on etcd health check while setting up RKE cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher, rke

i'm trying to set up a rke cluster, the connection to the nodes goes well but when it starts to check etcd health returns:
failed to check etcd health: failed to get /health for host [xx.xxx.x.xxx]: Get "https://xx.xxx.x.xxx:2379/health": remote error: tls: bad certificate

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upgrade the RKE and facing this issue then it could be due to the missing of `kube_config_<file>.yml` file from the local directory when you perform rke up.

This similar kind of issue was reported and reproduced in this [git link](https://github.com/rancher/rke/issues/1244#issuecomment-481644616) . Can you refer to the work around and reproduce it by using the steps provided in the link and let me know if this works.

Refer to this latest [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603038/rancher-rke-up-errors-on-etcd-host-health-checks-remote-error-tls-bad-certific) and [doc](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1043/how-to-solve-kubernetes-upgrade-rancher-2-failing-error-bad-certificate) for more information.